# How to re-size text and css background image like <img> is re-sizing in this example?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

In this example `<img>` is re-sizing as I want

**Edit: re-added** http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/yBkFL/

But I also want to re-size Discount tag and text. if I re-size the browser window to small size then Discount tag 20% and text "Good Product" should also re-size.

[image]

I need compatibility with IE8 and 9 and latest firefox, Chorme and iPad safari

I would like to do with CSS only but if it's not possible then use of javascript/jquery is ok. Compatibility is important.

**Important part of HTML and CSS**

**HTML (edited)**

```
<ul>
 <li>
   <span class="twenty-percent">
     <span class="rotate">20%</span>
   </span>
     <img src="image.jpg">
   <span class="description">Good Product</span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

**CSS (Edited:)**

```
    li {
    float: left;
    width: 18%;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    margin: 15px;
    background: yellow;
    display: inline }

img { width: 100%; }

li img { display: block; }

.twenty-percent {
    content: '';
    background:url(http: //i.imgur.com/9cfK5.png) no-repeat;
    position: absolute;
    right: -15px;
    top: -2px;
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px; }

.description {
    display: block;
    font-size: 120%; }

.rotate {
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-right: 10px;
    position: absolute;
    right: -5px;
    text-shadow: 0 1px 1px #000000;
    top: 9px; }
```

Comment: Fonts won't resize themselves without JS.  That said, one cross-browser way to do it would be with SVG and a library like Raphael or something.  Another (I think simpler) way would be to just make everything into background images

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a pure CSS way to do it, but with a bit of jQuery, it's possible as follows:

```
/* Original width of the description element */
var origWidth = $('.description').width();

/* Function to set the font size of description.  Based on its current width
   compared to its original width.  The * 70 is a factor you can use to increase
   or decrease the calculated font size. */
var setFontSize = function(){
    var $desc = $('.description');
    $desc.css({fontSize:  $desc.width()/origWidth * 70 + "%"});
}

/* Set the font size on load and when the viewport resizes */
setFontSize();    
$(window).resize(setFontSize);
```

[Here's a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Ju2sc/17/) of it.

**Notes**

1. Above assumes all `.description` elements are same width.
2. You could improve the appearance of the script by hiding the text until the font size was calculated on load.  This would prevent the font size jump you see before the first call to `setFontSize()`.
3. If you wanted to improve the font size ratio (rather than rely on the hardcoded `* 70` factor), you could use a function on load that calculated the maximum possible space for text in your `.description`.  Then you could use this value to determine the factor.

**Updated:** New version of the code that resizes the green percentage discount text and image as well.

**HTML**

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <!-- Green circle background has been changed to an <img>.  Now it
             can be scaled as the size changes.  It is absolutely positioned
             behind the percentage text.  -->
        <span class="percent">
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/9cfK5.png"/>
            <span class="rotate">20%</span>
        </span>
        <img src="http://lorempixum.com/100/200/">
        <span class="description">Good Product</span>
    </li>
    <!-- Remaining items -->
</ul>
```

**CSS**

```
/* Container that holds percent text and green circle <img> */ 
.percent {
    content: '';
    position:absolute;
    right:-15px;
    top:-2px;
    height: 45px;
    width: 45px;

    /* Vertically center percent text */
    line-height: 45px;
    font-size: 100%;
}

/* Green circle image */ 
.percent img {

    /* Grow/shrink as .percent size changes */
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

    /* Absolutely position behind percentage text */
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;   
}

.rotate {
    /* Positions percent text above green circle <img> */
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;

    /* Keeps text centered as size changes */
    display: block;
    text-align: center;

    /* remaining rules */
}
```

**jQuery**

```
/* Get common element references */
var $desc = $('.description');
var $percent = $('.percent');

/* Store the original values.  We'll use these to smoothly change the size */
var orig = {
    description: $desc.width(),
    percent: $percent.width(),
    right: parseInt($percent.css('right'), 10)  
};

/* Sets font sizes and changes green circle image size and position */
var setFontSize = function(){  

    /* Get the percent of size change */
    var change = $desc.width()/orig.description;  

    /* Update the .description font-size */
    $desc.css({
        fontSize:  change * 100 + "%"
    });

    /* Update the following .percent properties:
       1. font-size
       2. width: to grow/shrink green circle image
       3. line-height: to keep percent text vertically centered
       4. right: keeps .percent container in the same proportional position */
    $percent.css({
        fontSize:  change  * 100 + "%",
        width: orig.percent * change + "px",
        lineHeight: orig.percent * change + "px",
        right: orig.right * change + "px"
    });

} 

/* Set the font size on load and when the viewport resizes */
setFontSize();    
$(window).resize(setFontSize);
```

[Demo of it](http://jsfiddle.net/MTSnM/4/) in action.

Comment: @JitendraVyas Ah nuts, firewall is blocking the discount image domain so I didn't notice it in your fiddle :/  To resize that, the easiest approach would be to change your markup so that it was an absolutely positioned `<img>`.  Then you could apply similar logic as the font size calculation to increase/decrease its size by a percent value.

Comment: I cannot use <img> for discount image. because actually i will use 20% as a text over green background

Comment: @JitendraVyas in that case can you scale the 20% text as in the `.description` example and use a repeating background image on your `.discount`?  Another possibility if your green background can't repeat would be to absolutely position an element with the 20% text overtop of an absolutely positioned `<img>`, thereby creating the appearance that the `<img>` is the 20% text element's background.

Comment: @pat- I edited my question a bit and example too. check this new fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jitendravyas/yBkFL/ and give your suggestion now. 20% is selectable text now.

Comment: +1 ok so it's not possible to resize background image. we will have to use <img>. but your solution is good

Comment: The problem is your jsfiddle example is that it works fine when I open it on big resolution and resize. but if I open it on small width like 800px then font-size is big. see screenshot http://i.imgur.com/Qqcnb.jpg

Comment: If you want the font size to be appropriate to whatever screen resolution you open in, you'll need to perform some onload logic.  Its purpose would be to determine the correct size of font, relative to the size of the `.discription` container.

Answer (score 0):

You could create two css classes that describe the two sizes/versions that you want.  You can use jquery to detect the browser size and add and remove the appropriate css classes to your liking.

Answer (score 0):

Background images do not rescale themselves like images (`<img>` tags). Change the 20% logo to an `<img>`, then size it as you do the larger image.  Fonts can be sized as percents, so try setting the font-size to 120%.

Answer (score 0):

To resize text, create the block of whichit is contained within in CSS. for example: Body, Main, Footer etc. then simply use the **font-size** command. Like so

```
    body {
Font-size:1.1EM;
}
```

For the image, simply set the dimension which the want the image to be, although I recommend making the image file smaller, since this will save memory space.